# .htaccess Rewrite rules AND &&

Tags: .htaccess

I want to do one Rewrite Rule for htaccess

```
RewriteRule !packages/paymentmode/(.+?) AND !.*\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|js|css|swf)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But i don't know how change `AND`, to do this rule correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !packages/paymentmode/(.+?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|js|css|swf)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: +1 This should work. I suggest OP to use `[NC]` and get rid of unnecessary capture groups as well.